When does a cofibrantly generated model category have this factorization property?
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a cofibrantly generated model category, which is generated by $I$ and $J$. According to the small object argument (Hovey Theorem 2.1.14) of cofibrantly generated model categories, each map $X\to Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$ could be factored as
$$X\xrightarrow{i} Z \xrightarrow{r} Y,$$
where $i$ is a relative $I$-cell complex and $r$ is a weak equivalence. But now, I need the cofibrantly generated model category $\mathcal{C}$ to satisfy the extra following property:
For any finite $I$-cell complex $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$, the fold map $(\mathsf{id}_X,\mathsf{id}_X)\colon X\amalg X \to X$ could always be factored as
$$X\amalg X \xrightarrow{(i_0,i_1)} X' \xrightarrow{r} X$$
where $(i_0,i_1)$ is a relative finite $I$-cell complex and $r$ is a weak equivalence.
(To avoid misunderstanding, a relative finite $ I $‑cell complex means that both the factorization and the coproduct of morphisms in $I$ are finite.)
I think this property is not established for every cofibrantly generated model categories, but I also think it is not a very strong restriction. So I was wondering if there are some "deeper meaning" of this property (in a more general view)? or some large classes of cofibrantly generated model categories (maybe with extra structure such as enrich structure) has this property?
Additionally, the category $\mathbf{Top}$ (or $\mathbf{SSet}$) is too special for an example of this property, since the "middle object" $X'=X\times [0,1]$ of such factorization is generated by the catesian product, and the finiteness of $X\times [0,1]$ also rely on the catesian product. And I also read Williamson's thesis  Cylindrical model structures , it looks like it satisfies this property, but as I said I think this property may not depend on the "cylindrical structure".

I've encountered that condition a few time. Here is what I know about it:
If that property is satisfied for a model category $M$ then the full subcategory $C$ of finite $I$-cell complex is itself a Brown category of cofibrant object.
So they both have $\infty$-category attached to them: $h_\infty(M)$ which is locally presentable and $h_\infty(C)$ which his finitely co-complete. If we add the assumption that all maps in $I$ are between finitely presentable objects of $C$, then $h_\infty(M)$ is $\omega$-presentable with
$$h_\infty(M) \simeq Ind(h_\infty(C)) $$
(the ind completion)
Conversely, given any small Brown category of cofibrant objects $C$ you can build canonically a $\omega$-combinatorial left semi-model category $M$ such that $C$ identitfies with the finite $I$-cell complex in $M$. (and hence $M$ is a model for the infinity category cal ind completion of $C$).
Another remark is that all this can be generalized from "finite" to "$\lambda$-small" for any $\lambda$ and if $M$ is a combinatorial model category then there is $\lambda$ such that it satisfies these conditions (i.e. $\lambda$-small $I$-complex have cylinder that are relative $\lambda$-small complex ).
Some of these claims appears in this paper of mine, the rest can be justified from there (except the clain about $\infty$-categories, that will be in an upcoming work).

Thank you so much for your answer! It really looks like what I want to know! I can see most of your points, except the $h_{\infty}$ part (I will read your paper seriously later).  However, I have a stupid question. I am not sure that a cofibration between finite $I$-cell complexes is always a relative $I$-cell complex (if it is relative, the finiteness is automatic).

So when we try to construct a semi-model category with that property as you described, we should consider whether the factorization axioms of the Brown category satisfying finiteness (the first cofibration in the factorization is a relative (finite) $I$-cell complex) at first?

I'm not sure I understood the question correctly but: Theorem 2.4 in the linked paper implies that if you start with a finitely presentable category and $I$ generating cofibrations between finitely presentable objects.  Then if the category of finite $I$-cell complex is a Brown category where the cofibration are the relative $I$-cell complexes (which is closely related to having a factorization as in the question) then this extend into a left semi-structure on the whole category which is cofibrantly generated by $I$ and by the set of "trivial cofibrations" of the Brown category.

... Note that condition (iii') of the theorem is obtained from a relative cylinder by taking B=B' and C to be the relative cylinder $B \coprod_A B \hookrightarrow C \overset{\sim}{\to} B$

Sorry for my stupidity. May I ask you what will the class $J$ in Theorem 2.4 be in this case? Thank you so much!

It can be any class that satisfies the assumption of the theorem. But it is meant to be the class of trivial cofibrations between cofibrant $\kappa$-presentable objects. Typically in the situation I was talking about above where you have a Brown category J is the class of cofibrations that are weak equivalences.

Actually I am really confused about the existence of $J$, when we have already had a finitely presentable category $\mathcal{C}$ with cofibrations (between finitely presentable objects) generated by $I$, and a Brown category of finite $I$-cell complex (where the cofibrations are the relative $I$-cell complexes).
